# Hide and Show button depend on JSON response object or field text value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to hide and show button depend on json response or field text value.

So far I tried with this code:

**two buttons**

```
<span id="1" class="tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
<input id="submit1" class=" btn btn-primary " type="submit" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#success-modal"  title="" value="1" style="display:none;">
</span>
<span id="2" class="tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
<input id="submit2" class=" btn btn-primary " type="submit" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#success-modal"  title="" value="2" style="display:none;">
</span>
```

Input field value came from json response

**input field**

```
<input type="text" id="service_type" name="service_type" value="abc">
```

since using json response not working, i tried to assign json response into field, but still not working

But not working,
Here my json response

```
{"timestamp":"2019-09-18T01:44:00+0700","sn":"P00475","subt":"abc"}
```

**js**

```
$('input[name=service_type]').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val()=='abc')
    $('#1').show();
  else
    $('#2').hide();
});
```

what i want to achieved is, if value on input type (or json subt as "abc") than the second button within id #2 will hide.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the HTTP request which you are using to get a response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

try this(Updated):

```
 $('#service_type').keyup(function(){    
    if ($('#service_type').val()==''){
     $('#1 input, #2 input').css('display', 'none');
    }else if($('#service_type').val()=='abc'){

        $('#1 input').css('display', 'block');
        $('#2 input').css('display', 'none');
      }else{
        $('#2 input').css('display', 'block');
         $('#1 input').css('display', 'none');
         }
    });
```

Demo is [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/9aey2xsk/)

View this try:
Re-edited [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n7zr6b8v/)

Comment: Input is not available for typing. He is directly putting the value from JSON response.

Comment: I was possibly confused by KEYUP jquery option. however the idea remains the same... just follow the input value changes - possibly more relevant to use ONCHANGE

Answer (score 0):

remove `style="display:none;"` from the `<span>` try using `$('#1').hide();` and `$('#2').hide();`

```js
$('#1').hide(); //hide first
$('#2').hide();//hide second

var json_data = JSON.stringify({"timestamp":"2019-09-18T01:44:00+0700","sn":"P00475","subt":"abc"});
result = JSON.parse(json_data);
console.log(result.subt)
  if(result.subt=="abc") //if value='abc' then hide second,show first
  {
    $('#1').show();
    $('#2').hide();

    }
  else //else hide first and show second
  {   
   $('#1').hide();
   $('#2').show();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="1" class="tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
<input id="submit1" class=" btn btn-primary " type="submit" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#success-modal"  title="" value="1">
</span>
<span id="2" class="tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
<input id="submit2" class=" btn btn-primary " type="submit" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#success-modal"  title="" value="2">
</span>
```

Comment: Input is not available for typing. He is directly putting the value from JSON response.

Comment: @AlokMali wait i will modify my solution

Comment: @AlokMali check my solution. you can replace the hardcoded json response and try it !